# Can you inject PoE on a disabled port to turn it on/reset it?

Tags: power-over-ethernet

I have an WLAN-AP (Aironet 2600) with just one Eth port that I accidently disabled. As there is no power plug available for now - is there a possibility to run PoE over the disabled port to power it on?

Or maybe can you PoE the console port?

I need a possibility to undo my 'shutdown' command on the Eth-Port, without buying said power plug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the Aironet AP can still be powered over the disabled Eth-Port by a PoE Injector! After the device was booted up again, I just accessed the CLI over the provided console port and re-enabled the Eth-Interface.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  However, this just seems to confirm a piece of JustAGrump's answer without really adding anything.

Comment: Not quite - sounds like he managed to power it up through an administratively down port - then enabled the port another way? wifi?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Exactly, I powered the device over the disabled Eth Port and enabled the Eth-Port over the console port!

Comment: Its a little unclear if you don't know cisco-ese. Might want to flesh out your answer with that

Answer (score 2):

The way you're asking the question is confusing. I see 3 questions in this.

1. Can you enable a "disabled" port by forcing PoE though the switch.

No

2. Can you PoE the console port?

Yes you can, will it do anything? Most likely not and you risk the chance of damaging the console port.

3. I need a possibility to 'no shut' the disabled port again, without buying said power plug.

I honestly have no idea what this means. Are you trying to say you want to able to locked the port from being disabled again? What does that have anything to do with a power plug? Are you trying to power the device with PoE?

If you're trying to reset the unit, which to me is your best option, you should be able to using these step:
https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/lan-switching-and-routing/problem-image-in-cisco-access-point-2600/td-p/2319731

Comment: iirc no shut is an IOS command for enabling a port,I'm guessing the device does POE, or runs off a wallwart.